# How to use emoji in email subject line, send via PHPMailerClass

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

We are trying to send email with Emoji in subject line using our Email Api which is using PHPmailer class and powerMTA port25 for relay.
surprisingly when Email sent from our Email Api reachs yahoo and when we look into "view raw message" our subject looks like:

```
=?utf-8?Q?=F0=9F=91=89_Overtake_The_Year_End_Price_Drop.?=
what we sent was:
 Overtake The Year End Price Drop
```

On the other hand when look into email sent from some random ESP it's "view raw message" appears as what they had sent:

```
Subject: Updates on Your Pre-Approved Loan offer
```

Please help to understand where things are getting wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Set PHPMailer to use UTF-8, then go ahead and use it:

```php
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
$mail->Subject = ' Overtake…';
```

Comment: "view raw message" of both email header shows Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8  and checked in mailer class its already public $CharSet = 'utf-8';

Comment: Set `SMTPDebug = 2` and show the output. You will be able to see whether the content in the header is correctly encoded. The content needs to be encoded if any server on the delivery route does not support SMTPUTF8, because you can't put UTF-8 in message headers without it (the same is not true of message bodies). PHPMailer doesn't support it, but encoding should work fine – I use it frequently.